# How to get details page and follow the links with Scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm having problem. I want to crawl an adult story websites. And I have many websites to crawl. For example, I want to crawl 2 websites, like below :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class Cerita(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "cerita"
   allowed_domains = [
      "ceritabokep.me",
      "ceritangewe.com"
   ]

   start_urls = [
       'http://ceritabokep.me/',
       'https://ceritangewe.com'
   ]

   def parse(self, response):
      divs = response.xpath('//div')
      for p in divs.xpath('.//p'):
        yield {
            'content': p.extract(),
            'url': response.request.url
        }

    next_page = response.css('a::attr(href)')
    if next_page is not None:
        for href in response.css('a'):
            yield response.follow(href, callback=self.parse)
```

I just want to get paragraph or text in each page websites. But when I run the spider, spider just crawl the highlights in homepage not until to details page. Like below:

```
[
{"content": "<p itemprop=\"description\" class=\"post_excerpt\">Seperi biasa 
akhir pekan semua terlihat santai tidak melakukan aktivitas tapi seperti 
biasa ibuku menghadiri arisan ibu berpesan untuk menjaga rumah,\nibu : 
\u201cJovita, ibu mau arisan di antar sama adik, kamu jaga rumah 
ya\u201d\naku : \u201cia ibu ku sayang, Jovita dirumah aja kok\u201d  \u00a0  
ibu : \u201cooo...</p>", "url": "http://ceritabokep.me/"},
{"content": "<p itemprop=\"description\" class=\"post_excerpt\">Aku kerja 
sebagai trainer berenang disatu sport hall yang berada di kawasan prumahan 
elit yang mayoritas penghuninya warga keturunan. Perumahannya mewah, rumahnya 
gak banyak tapi besar-besar. Sport Hallnya lengkap,lapangan tenis, gym,kolam 
renang,malah disediakan juga lapangan basket merangkap volley dan bulu 
tangkis.kalo peralatan untuk tenis meja...</p>", "url": 
"http://ceritabokep.me/"},
]
```

It's disconnected because link *Read More*
And I want crawl all pages on the website, how to follow all pages link and get details page? Because each website has different element.

Answer (score 0):

You want to crawl discover article urls in multiple domains, to do that you need to build a case for each website or use some smart algorithm that can determine what urls are articles.

The easiest way if you have only few websites like in your example just code in cases:

```
def parse(self, response): 
    # css selector for domain #1
    articles = response.css('h5 a::attr(href)').extract()
    if not articles:
        # if nothing found use css selector for domain #2
        articles = response.css('h2 a::attr(href)').extract()
```

Alternatively form your examples you can see that all articles have `/cerita` in their url on both domains:

```
def parse(self, response): 
    # css selector for domain #1
    urls = response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
    articles = [url for url in urls if '/cerita' in url]
```